# Where do I translate a string?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Where is the page in the administrative section where I can put the translations in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the "Interface Translation", it should be available under this URL => http://foo.bar/admin/config/regional/translate

If you clear the cache after activating the Interface Translation module, you could also see this option under "Configuration" >> "Regional and language" >> "User interface translation" menu